# Flutter: Http Request has no body

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to send a http request using the http plugin on version ^0.12.0+4 (the latest one).

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
    http://localhost:8085,
    body: jsonEncode({"test": "test"}),
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
);
```

I have a SpringBoot backend running which stated, that the request body is empty. Debug attempts with Postman worked fine.

I tried the Dio package as well with the same result.

Comment: What's the status code of the response in Flutter?

Comment: Ok the solution was a CORS issue. The problem was that no (visible) exception was thrown (so no stacktrace in the log whatsoever) and i assumed that the request was sent correctly.

I disabled CORS on my backend for now and it works fine, thank you for your help.